# Customizing Spring Cloud Stream in more depth

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have started to use spring cloud stream and some questions have come up from other team members on the depth to which you can customize.
Specifically:

1. detailed configuration access to the exchange
2. separation of the exchange from the queue
3. queue customization
4. publish messages to an exchange based on a customizable routing key
5. binding queues to an exchange based on a routing key

I understand that spring cloud stream is intended to get one up and running quickly, but for those who want to custom in depth, are there options or should we skip it and go straight to spring integration or spring rabbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the queues/exchanges exactly as you want before deploying - the binder will check to see if they exist already before declaring them the standard way.

There is currently no mechanism for changing the standard configuration used when auto-declaring these elements. Nor can you change the routing key.